# Modifying state directly in react -- why is it working?

Tags: reactjs

My code works, so I'm not asking for help in that regard, but I want to understand why it's working as it is- react theory 101. I like to study things that I come across so I can get predictable results in the future.

I have two similar objects:

```js
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({})
  const formState = {}
```

Both intended to serve the same purpose. I only need one of them, whichever works.

I'm prop drilling down several layers. I'm running a multiple step modal gathering client input to send to server. I am collecting data but that doesn't have to constitute 'state' insofar as it's not going to change the rendering/User Interface. It's passively collected. Do I need to use 'state'?

It turns out when I clicked the choices to a question, formState captured the values and they got logged to the console.

[image]

However when I went to another questions on a new page, the old data got dropped.

[image: Picture of console log]

I had to go to the drawing board. Actually I figured I would have to use the setFormData hook, and manage state after all. I didn't expect it to trigger any re-renders because I'm not using the data in my view. Nothing would be a DOM 'hit'.

Well it seems like the fact that this is a useState wrapped object made the different because the object persists and compiles or aggregates past data with current data:

[image]

However, the interesting thing is I never actually ended up calling setFormData. I simply modified formData directly just as I did with the other. The difference it seems was just the wrapper, and it let me do it without complaint.

```js
const handleClick = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>, p: ViewProps, data: string|number) =>
{
  let qn = p.question.question // => question-number
  console.log(qn, data)
  p.formProps.formState[qn] = data // identical ...
  p.formProps.formData[qn] = data //       ...  operations
  console.log('form state', p.formProps.formState)
  console.log('form data', p.formProps.formData)
}
```

A few things are surprising to me. Even using `const` for the object formState (implying a constant reference to a location in memory, that I think would stay in the same blockscope of the parent), it resets or flushes out or overwrites the data somehow [can't log memory address in js], but the useState-wrapped formData does not flush. It must be held by react in a true single memory location, a true singleton in a memory bank somewhere, or?

Lastly, even though I was using a useState wrapped object, I didn't need to change it with setFormData. Is this a 'hack' or is this something they build in for use cases like this or is this something they just can't avoid even if they want to? I can see how modifying state directly would not work if you're making a component that needs to re-render. How else would React know if control doesn't pass to one of React's core functions? But if you don't plan to use it for rendering, and you aren't going to ever call setState, would it make a difference from a theory POV? The same button they click will send them to my next page anyway. I do see from reading the docs that if you do call setState later, it could wipe your data, and these two things are the vast majority of use cases. I was mostly surprised it worked so smoothly when the direct modification of a non-state object didn't.

What are your thoughts? Is my thinking correct? I don't mean to over-state the obvious. I'm actually at the edge of my knowledge on these subjects and this is how I push that edge.

Comment: It looks like *something* is causing a re-render, which will negate the requirement to call the state setter function, but I don't see anything setting state in the click handler

Comment: nothing sets it in the click handler. I thought I'd have to. I probably should for best practices/data safety, but I didn't "have to" to get the data to log and persist. I don't know if there's a re-render between clicks on a single page. How can you tell? I don't see DOM lighting up and I don't see any reason for it. But there's a re-render between the two examples I showed, as they're on different pages=>i.e. renders.